# Sinatra and Bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, rack, bundler

I'm trying to get Bundler setup so I can deploy my Sinatra app to server with all the correct gems.

I've created my Gemfile

```
source :gemcutter
gem 'sinatra', '1.0'
gem "nokogiri", "1.4.2"
gem "rack",  "1.1.0"
gem "dm-core",  "1.0.0"
gem "dm-migrations",  "1.0.0"
gem "dm-sqlite-adapter",  "1.0.0"
gem "pony", "1.0"
```

Next I created a Config.ru

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup

require 'sinatra'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'dm-sqlite-adapter'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'
require 'pony'
require 'parsedate'
require 'digest/md5'

require 'MyApp'
run MyApp
```

So far so good, so next I ran `bundle install` and got 'Bundle Complete' so now all I need to do is just `Rackup`

Then I get:

```
config.ru:18: undefined local variable or method `MyApp' for #<Rack::Builder:0x1227350 @ins=[]> (NameError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
from config.ru:1:in `new'
from config.ru:1
```

Here's a simple MyApp.rb which will trigger the same error

```
get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

What's going wrong? :(

Comment: Can you show us your MyApp.rb?

Comment: Hey, I've reduced down MyApp.rb to something that triggers the same error :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you tell Rack to `run MyApp`, you need to define class MyApp first (which you're supposed to do inside MyApp.rb). Derive your class from Sinatra::Base to make it a Sinatra-Rack-App that can be run from config.ru:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    erb :index
  end
end
```

See also Sinatra's README about modular Sinatra apps (search for the paragraph named "Modular Apps" on http://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/)

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working ok now. I'd never come across Sinatra::Base before.

Just to note that I updated my Config.ru to read "MyApp.run! :host => 'localhost', :port => 9090" didn't realised I also had to bind a port in there to get it started up.

Comment: Using MyApp.run! inside config.ru is probably not, what you want. MyApp.run! starts a new server process that serves your app (therefore you need to tell it the port). Inside config.ru, you want to tell the already running webserver (the one that just started up and is parsing config.ru, e.g. unicorn) how to direct http requests to your app (by telling it `run MyApp` inside config.ru). MyApp.run! starts up a completely different standalone server that (afaik) does not use config.ru, it's meant for standalone usage (e.g. during development) and should not be used inside config.ru.

Comment: Thanks, yep MyApp.Run! is totally not what I wanted at all.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you may have your **my_app.rb** as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup

require 'sinatra'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'dm-sqlite-adapter'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'
require 'pony'
require 'parsedate'
require 'digest/md5'
```

And your **config.ru** like this:

```
require './my_app'
run Rack::URLMap.new '/' => Sinatra::Application
```

Hope this helps.

Best Regards

ED

Comment: The URLMap there is just adding complexity, `run Sinatra::Application` will give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to creating a modular app (wrapping your Sinatra methods in a class extending `Sinatra::Base`), you can use:

```
run Sinatra::Application
```

in the `config.ru` file in place of

```
run MyApp
```

This might be a better option if you want to keep the simple Sinatra code.

See [the docs for more info](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Using%20a%20Classic%20Style%20Application%20with%20a%20config.ru).